# "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.humblefinancialservices.com/deferredfunctions.js" Firebug

Tags: firebug, http-status-code-404

Just to let you know that I'm still learning wordpress so please keep that in mind with answers.

I always have this error (used `Firebug error code` but pops up on other testing software) `NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.humblefinancialservices.com/deferredfunctions.js` Firebug

I have no idea what it is. the error seems to be on every page, ie the same error repaeats on all the pages.
it does slow my website down quite considerably. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A bit off topic, if you are using a free Wordpress template this reminds me of an article: http://wpmu.org/why-you-should-never-search-for-free-wordpress-themes-in-google-or-anywhere-else/

Answer (score 0):

You have included Javascript file somewhere in your HTML code pointing to `http://www.humblefinancialservices.com/deferredfunctions.js`

So everytime you open you page, this is downloaded also.
If you site works without this script just remove it from you wordpress template.

Answer (score 0):

This error shows that something is included in your code that the browser is unable to locate.In your case the browser cannot find the link you have mentioned.Check your code again.And if you are using firebug it can help you find exact location in the code where the change is required.